# Converting .pcm to aac while recording from mic

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, pcm, android-audiorecord, mediamuxer

I have a program that records sound from microphone and saves the sound in a .pcm file.

I have a separate function in the program that converts .pcm to aac using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer.

Is it possible to modify my program so that directly converts .pcm to aac using a MediaCodec?How can I do that? Is there a guide or is there a code sample to do that?

Here is a code snippet from my program that records sound from the 
microphone:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord(
    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 
    RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, 
    RECORDER_CHANNELS, 
    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, 
    bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;

    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filePathAudioRec);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isRecording) {
        // gets the voice output from microphone to byte format

        recorder.read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);
        try {
            // writes the data to file from buffer
            // stores the voice buffer
            byte bData[] = short2byte(sData);
            os.write(bData, 0, BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement); //do I need to write it to a file ??
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
// inside while loop: add code to convert to .mp4 while the data is collected from the MIC
   }
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for your question? Or if you have a solution will you share it here? Thanks!